# Special 3 Variable Function

Tags: functions

Does there exist a function that maps from two variable to one variable, such that it only yields the same value for two vectors when they are perpendicular and have the same magnitude. Obviously parallel vectors  would have to yield the same value I assume.

In other words, prove or disprove the following statement:
$\exists f\ni f\left( x_{1},y_{1}\right) =f\left( x_{2},y_{2}\right)\Leftrightarrow \dfrac {x_{1}} {y_{1}}=\dfrac {-y_{2}} {x_{2}}$ and $ \sqrt{(x_{1})^2+(y_{1})^2}=\sqrt{(x_{2})^2+(y_{2})^2}$

where I use the $\ni$ symbol to mean such that.

Answer (score 1):

This is false: Lets say there exist such function (If I understood correctly)

$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$f(v)=f(u) \Leftrightarrow u \perp v$

Since $(1,0) \perp (0,1)$ then $f(0,1)=f(1,0)$

Since $(2,0) \perp (0,1)$ then $f(0,2)=f(1,0)$

Consequently you have that $f(1,0)=f(2,0)$ $\implies$ (By hypothesis) $(1,0) \perp (2,0)$

Which is absurd.

Maybe without the double implication you can.

Comment: I apologize, but I have edited it to fix that problem I believe